# How to stop getting sound of another phone call

Tags: samsung

have a Samsung G7 and am getting much problem with the call waiting...

I want to know if it is possible when am on already on a phone call and another person phones and the person with whom am taking is getting the sound of the another one phone call. Thus I want to know how to remove the sound when the another person is calling..

Answer (score 1):

You can disable "knocking" at all – so that the second caller gets a "busy" signal, and you a "missed call" notification. If that's what you want, depending on your device the setting might be in the phone app:

- open the phone app
- tap the overflow icon (the 3 stapled dots in the upper right corner)
- select *Settings*
- chose *Advanced Settings*

There you should find the option. If it's not there, an USSD code can toggle that:

- open the phone app
- pretend you want to make a call to the number `#43#` (enter that code and tap the call button)

Now it should be turned off. If you want to turn it on again, use `*43#`, to check the status `*#43#`.

Comment: +1. Didn't know this and maybe carrier /device specific but I got a notification that says Call waiting disabled / enabled

Comment: @beeshyams on some devices I have the option in the dialer (up to MM). On my latest (Nougat) it's gone, hence the USSD codes. They work device independently.